# Wrap org src block results

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'd like to include a custom latex wrapper around src blocks result. For example, given:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results latex
which awk
#+END_SRC
```

I'd like to generate

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
\begin{myverbatim}
/usr/bin/awk
\end{myverbatim}
#+END_LaTeX
```

Instead of the standard

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
/usr/bin/awk
#+END_LaTeX
```

Is there a straightforward way to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to restrict your output to LaTeX there is no reason to wrap in `#+begin_latex . #+end_latex`.   As such, you could simply use the `wrap` keyword.

`emacs -q` example:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages 
               '((shell .  t)))
  (insert "
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :wrap myverbatim :exports results
which awk
#+END_SRC")
  (org-latex-export-as-latex nil nil nil t))
```

`=>`

```
\begin{myverbatim}
/usr/bin/awk
\end{myverbatim}
```

Comment: Great - much simpler than defining a custom wrapper. Is there a header argument analogous to `wrap` that can wrap the src block itself when using `:exports both`?

Comment: No.  You should make request for `org-latex-listings` to accept a formatting string.  `minted` and `listings` is supported out of the box.  Or you could send a patch on `org-latex-inline-src-block`.  Alternatively, if `myverbatim` is a fixed string I'd just use a filter to `org-export-filter-src-block-functions` using `replace-regexp-in-string` to change `verbatim` to `myverbatim`.

Comment: I just discovered `org-latex-custom-lang-environments`, which seems like it should do the trick, but haven't figured it out. Is there a reason that setting it to `((sh "myverbatim"))` wouldn't affect export?

Comment: Turns out I needed to also set `org-latex-listings` to `t`. With that done, `org-latex-custom-lang-environments` does what I need.

Comment: Of course.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194347/org-mode-with-code-example-as-html

```
* test using post-wrap
  #+name: wrap-myverbatim
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :var text="" :exports none
    (concat "\\begin{myverbatim}\n"
            text "\n\\end{myverbatim}\n")
  #+end_src

  #+BEGIN_SRC sh :results latex :post wrap-myverbatim(text=*this*)
    which awk
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  #+BEGIN_LaTeX
  \begin{myverbatim}
  /usr/bin/awk
  \end{myverbatim}
  #+END_LaTeX
```

Comment: (i) The `results` header in `wrap-myverbatim` is redundant.  (ii) you can combine `post` and `results` which would allow you move out `#+begin_latex . #+end_latex` of `wrap-myverbatim`.

Comment: @rasmus yeh, right, updated the answer.